# :focus-within only works when focusing button with keyboard, not with click in Firefox 63

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a field layout with an outer div (`.field`) and the label, input and a button inside that field. When I focus the input field, the `:focus-within` pseudo selector matches, so `.field__inner` gets an outer border color.

When I use tab to cycle through the elements, the `:focus-within` matches when I focus the input field or the button.

But when I click the button, `:focus-within` doesn't seem to 'trigger' (it works in Chrome though).

I've tried to add a `tabindex` attribute to the button, but that had no effect.

I am using Firefox 63 on macOS.

```css
.field__inner {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.field:focus-within .field__inner {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <div class="field__inner">
    <label for="password" class="field__label">
      Name
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="field__input" value="">
    <button class="field__passwordreveal" type="button">
      Click this button!               
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I maintain `:focus-within` in Firefox when I click the button?

**Edit:** added animated gif to demonstrate the issue:

[image]

Comment: Works fine in ff/chrome and ie/edge don't support it. Clicking the button presents the red border so unable to reproduce.

Comment: Hmm that's odd. I've added an animated gif to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @ThijsKramer: Have you found a solution to this yet? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't found a solution yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retried this today in Firefox 98 on macOS, and it works as intended: the `:focus-within` fires when I click the button.

Time heals all wounds, and in this case it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for me as well but I found a clean workaround:

If you hook to the `onclick` event for either the parent (the one you select via `:focus-within`) or a child element, you can just retrieve the child element and force it to focus:

```html
<div onclick="document.getElementById(#child).focus()">
  <span id="child" />
</div>
```